# spinning-wheel in javascript with no Submit button

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript page which submits as it loads using
 `<body onload="javascript:document.Form.submit()">
<form action="myUrl" method="POST"....etc etc> 
</form> </body>`

Now I want to insert a spinning-wheel or hourglass while it loads as it takes few seconds to call the 
service at 'myUrl' above.
How do I do that?
Something like this didn't fix it.

```
 <form onsubmit="document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block'" action="myUrl">   

<img id='loading' src='spinning-wheel.gif' style="display:none;"/>   /<form>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @Teemu no purpose here but the service that the above actionUrl calls is in Java, just in case

Comment: Please tag questions with relevant tags only. I've removed the irrelevant tag.

Comment: sidenote: it says `styple` instead of `style` in your img-tag

Comment: and =d= instead of id=

Comment: made those corrections. But my actual code does not have those typos.

Comment: Is your submit posting data?  If so have you considered using AJAX to get the data rather than a submit?
This JSFiddle was created for me a while back with a spinny wheel.  It mocks the AJAX request:
http://jsfiddle.net/licson0729/gk3RL/2/

Comment: try `window.document.forms[0].submit()` for the onload event.